# Selenium WebDriver test of a Oracle ADF Task Flow application doesn't work on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, automated-tests, oracle-adf

I'm trying to run a Selenium WebDriver test that works on Firefox and Chrome but "surprisingly" (or not) doesn't work on Internet Explorer 11.

so far I've been able to discover that the problem is related to the fact that I am using AJAX and IE does not have the updated DOM Tree after the AJAX request.

So, How Can I force to reload a part of the DOM tree after a ajax request?

--

All the problems are related with timeout because selenium couldn't find some Element.

My Jdev version is Oracle JDeveloper 11g Release 1 (11.1.1.6.0)

Comment: Can you tell us your exact Jdev version, please? Some versions don't work with ie11 at all.

Comment: First have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Second consider that Selenium-RC has been deprecated several **years** ago, and is no longer being maintained. You might be better off switching to Selenium-WebDriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE 11, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For `32-bit Windows` installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`. For `64-bit Windows` installations, the key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`. Please note that the `FEATURE_BFCACHE` subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present.

**Important:** Inside this key, create a `DWORD` value named `iexplore.exe` with the value of `0`.

**References:**

[google code](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration)

[seleniumsimplified](http://seleniumsimplified.com/2014/06/a-quick-webdriver-2-42-2-retrospective/)

[seleniumhq docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp)

[jimevansmusic](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.in/2014/09/using-internet-explorer-webdriver.html)

[toolsqa](http://www.toolsqa.com/forums/topic/selenium-sendkeys-typing-slow-on-ie-11/)